# Display seems a bit blurred with MacMini 2012

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, thunderbolt

I have a 22" HD TV which I use with my 2008 MacBook through a mini-displayport -> HDMI cable. The display when I do that is really clear and crisp.

When I use the exact same cable and TV connected to my new 2012 Mac Mini (connected to the thunderbolt socket) the display is not so good. Text looks a bit like it does in a JPG which has compression set too high.

I've tried different settings but it hasn't helped. My TV and cable work fine with the MacBook so why would it be worse with a newer, more powerful Mac Mini?

I'm running Mavericks on both Macs.

[image]

I added this screen-capture, but it only looks bad on my MacMini not on my other PCs  so it must be the display somehow. Maybe DP->HDMI doesn't work well on the MacMini?

Comment: what profile is it using in the ColorSync Utility app.

Comment: I've no idea. I opened that app and it only tells me what is installed, not what is in use... it seems more interested in doing "profile first aid" whatever that is

Comment: when you select your monitor it should show you currently used and factory profiles. for example for my tv it has 2 profiles the HD and the SD

Comment: Those kind of things make no difference, neither does choosing scaling or manually selecting the resolution.